# View Hierarchical data as columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I have a self referencing table to store a hierarchy.

| vehicle_id | vehicle_name | parent_vehicle_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | social_media | NULL |
| 2 | facebook | 1 |
| 3 | instagram | 1 |
| 4 | stories | 2 |
| 5 | reel | 3 |
| 6 | igtv | 3 |

using a cte, I am able to get the vehicle levels like so

```sql
with vehicle_tree (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, parent_vehicle_id, veh_level)
as
(
select v.vehicle_id, v.vehicle_name, v.parent_vehicle_id, 1 as veh_level from vehicle as v where v.parent_vehicle_id is null
union all
select sub_veh.vehicle_id, sub_veh.vehicle_name, sub_veh.parent_vehicle_id, vt.veh_level + 1 from vehicle as sub_veh 
inner join vehicle_tree as vt
on vt.vehicle_id = sub_veh.parent_vehicle_id
where sub_veh.parent_vehicle_id is not null
)
select * from vehicle_tree
```

with the output

| vehicle_id | vehicle_name | parent_vehicle_id | veh_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | social_media | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | facebook | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | instagram | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | reel | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | igtv | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | stories | 2 | 3 |

What I would like to have, is to view the hierarchies as columns rather than rows something like this

| 1_id | 1 | 2_id | 2 | 3_id | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | social_media | 2 | facebook | 4 | stories |
| 1 | social_media | 3 | instagram | 5 | reel |
| 1 | social_media | 3 | instagram | 6 | igtv |

I have gotten as far as this

```sql
with vehicle_tree (vehicle_id, vehicle_name, parent_vehicle_id, veh_level)
as
(
select v.vehicle_id, v.vehicle_name, v.parent_vehicle_id, 1 as veh_level from vehicle as v where v.parent_vehicle_id is null
union all
select sub_veh.vehicle_id, sub_veh.vehicle_name, sub_veh.parent_vehicle_id, vt.veh_level + 1 from vehicle as sub_veh 
inner join vehicle_tree as vt
on vt.vehicle_id = sub_veh.parent_vehicle_id
where sub_veh.parent_vehicle_id is not null
)
select * from vehicle_tree l1
left outer join vehicle_tree l2 on l2.veh_level = 2 and l1.vehicle_id = l2.parent_vehicle_id
left outer join vehicle_tree l3 on l3.veh_level = 3 and l2.vehicle_id = l3.parent_vehicle_id
where l1.veh_level = 1
```

which gives the output that I expect but I would like to have some form of a recursive solution on the left outer joins instead

| vehicle_id | vehicle_name | parent_vehicle_id | veh_level | vehicle_id | vehicle_name | parent_vehicle_id | veh_level | vehicle_id | vehicle_name | parent_vehicle_id | veh_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | social_media | NULL | 1 | 2 | facebook | 1 | 2 | 4 | stories | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | social_media | NULL | 1 | 3 | instagram | 1 | 2 | 5 | reel | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | social_media | NULL | 1 | 3 | instagram | 1 | 2 | 6 | igtv | 3 | 3 |

Kindly advise how I can achieve the same output via a recursive function. I would prefer a solution that could be used on any engine but MS SQL will suffice for now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flattening of hierarchy in SQL Server Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897337/flattening-of-hierarchy-in-sql-server-dynamically)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Because a SQL query returns a fixed set of columns, you can just use explicit `JOIN`s to get the names in different columns:

```
select vt.*, vt2.*, vt3.*
from vehicle_tree vt left join
     vehicle_tree vt2
     on vt2.parent_vehicle_id = vt.vehicle_id left join
     vehicle_tree vt3
     on vt3.parent_vehicle_id = vt2.vehicle_id left join
where vt.parent_vehicle_id is null
```

Comment: yes thats what I have done as well! its in the question. I am looking for a way to make this dynamic in some way